# What's the difference between server-sent events and ajax request?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, server-sent-events

I need a notification in the user interface. You  have 4 new messages etc. . I did research and read the article here.

[server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

My goal is not to make a request by the server if the user has 0 new messages constantly or if there are 4 new messages constantly.

If the server message has changed, I want to take action on the client. So I will not tire the server.

However, sse works like an "ajax script" task that runs in 3 seconds. I never understood what the difference was.

My codes

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Get Data:";

if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("sse.asp");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

sse.asp

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
response.AddHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
Response.Expires = -1


data="4 New Messages"
response.flush
Response.Write "data: " & data &""& vbcrlf & vbcrlf
response.flush


%>
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way you've understood. It sends a message when the server does that. The difference between SSE and AJAX is that with AJAX you send a request and receive a response, while with SSE you open a session and that session remains open for the server to send messages.